# Get line_items from Shopify API into Google Sheets

Tags: json, shopify-api

I'm trying to make a Google Sheet that will pull information from my Shopify store into it using Google Apps Script. I would like to be able to grab a couple of different things and separate them into different cells. I'm mainly looking to extract a couple of parameters from `line_items`. I've got a code working that shows me all of the parameters for `line_items`, but I can't figure out how to show me only a couple of specific ones. The code is:

```
function shopify() {
var field = "line_items" 
var url = "https://store.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?status=any&created_at_min=2021-01-20T00:00:00-04:00&created_at_max=2021-01-21T00:00:00-04:00&fields=" + field + "&limit=250";
var username = "1234567890";
var password = "1234567890";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {"method":"get", "headers": {"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password)}});


Logger.log(response);
```

I'm looking to grab just the "variant_title" and "variant_id". If I change the field in the url to be `fields=line_items:variant_title` it still shows every line item for every order.

Is there a way to do this, or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure out how to get the specific line_items, but I found a work around.

```
var json = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(json);
var myJson = JSON.stringify(data.orders);

var array = myJson.match(/parameter/g);
```

I grabbed all of the order data from a json, then created a new array from it by only grabbing the parameter I needed. Maybe not the best way to do it, but at least it's working.